# New breaker and panel: What's the brown goo where they connect?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'll be replacing my electrical panel soon and I noticed that the new breakers and panel have a brown goo on them where they connect to one another. I'm guessing it is lubricant .. similar to what goes in the aluminum wires but I rather make sure than end up with fireworks.

Should I leave the brown goo in place before I plug the breakers to the new panel or should I wipe it out? Thanks.

[image: breaker]
[image: box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave it there. It's a [dielectric grease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone_grease#As_a_sealant_around_electrical_contacts) that prevents corrosion on the metal contacts. It probably does also act as a lubricant for easier installation.

Comment: The contacts aren't steel, but yes -- it's an antioxidant/dielectric material.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like no-ox-id. This is a special anti oxide lubricating grease.