# Why is there an oily substance on the connector in my circuit breaker?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a circuit breaker panel with 2 supply wires (2.5-4mm2 400V). I noticed that there is some oily substance dripping out of the supply contact of my circuit breaker. What is this substance and is it dangerous? The circuit breaker does not trip.

Because I live in a rather old building where the heating does not work well I often rely on electrical heaters, so I use much electricity, but the circuit breaker never trips. It is also a model without residual current circuit breaker.

It is more or less this model...

[image: Hager circuit breaker]

Comment: can you add a pic of the box, and the goo dripping from the breaker..  And when you say "Fuse Box"  I assume you mean "Circuit Breaker Panel"?  And Lastly, Sometime a dielectric grease is applied to the connections of a circuit breakers when they are installed, and it can appear to be dripping from the wires...

Comment: Also see this previous link: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/146945/new-breaker-and-panel-whats-the-brown-goo-where-they-connect#:~:text=It's%20a%20dielectric%20grease%20that,a%20lubricant%20for%20easier%20installation.

Comment: That's probably it..yes circuit breaker panel not fuse box..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime a dielectric grease is applied to the connections of a circuit breakers when they are installed, and it can appear to be dripping from the wires..

> diy.stackexchange.com/questions/146945/…
> Courtesy of Ed Beal And Isherwood

[image]

If this is it, leave it in place and don't worry it is supposed to be there.